# How to add multiple files into a single zip folder

Tags: python, zip

Actually i am writting a script which writes two files into a desktop, let it be as "a.txt" and "b.txt"....... so after writing into a desktop i have to read this files and zip into a folder....

can anyone help on this....i know how to zip a folder but dono how to add two files in to a zip

Reading from folder i know its like this

```
def zipdir(basedir, archivename):
    assert os.path.isdir(basedir)
    with closing(ZipFile(archivename, "w", ZIP_DEFLATED)) as z:
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(basedir):
            for fn in files:
                absfn = os.path.join(root, fn)
                zfn = absfn[len(basedir)+len(os.sep):]
                z.write(absfn, zfn)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    basedir = sys.argv[1]
    archivename = sys.argv[2]
    zipdir(basedir, archivename)
```

The code which now i using is

```
import zipfile
zip = zipfile.ZipFile('Python.zip', 'a')
zip.write('fields.txt')
zip.write('grp.txt')
zip.close()
```

This is creating file of those two plus some extra folder which contains all files.......

Comment: It's in the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html#zipfile-objects) and in the [zip file structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)#Structure) on wikipedia. Always check the docs before asking a question on SO.

Comment: `closing(ZipFile())` is redundant - `ZipFile()` is already a closing context manager in recent Python versions...

Answer (score 1):

you need to open the zip file with "a" -append parameter. Then you can use the write parameter without overwriting the file.

source: [12.4.1](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html#zipfile-objects)

EDIT:

zip.write('file.pdf','/folder/file.pdf')

Comment: @-aphex i got that and its working but its adding some extra folder which contains all files

Comment: I missunderstood your question... Also you can use it like this: zip.write('file.pdf','file.pdf') or zip.write('file.pdf',)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest wayh is to use shutil library. put all the files you want to zip in a single directoty(folder)

```
import shutil
shutil.make_archive(output_filename_dont_add_.zip, 'zip', directory_to_download)
```

Remember if you work with ipython you can use relative address for directory_to_download